# React useState can't be set in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning react and trying set object from queryStr for later reuse,
can't set searchFilter in useEffect

this line prinst null:
console.log(searchFilter.transactionId)//prints null

```
interface TransactionSearchFilter {
   transactionId?: number;
}

const TransactionList: any = (props: any) => {

const queryStr = location.search.substring(1);
const [searchFilter, setSearchFilter] = React.useState<TransactionSearchFilter>({
    transactionId: null,
});
const parseQueryParams = () => {
    const queryObj = QueryString.parse(queryStr);
    console.log(queryObj.transactionId)//prints 10
    setSearchFilter({ ...searchFilter, ...queryObj });
    console.log(searchFilter.transactionId)//prints null
};

React.useEffect(() => {
    parseQueryParams();
}, []);

return (<div>Hello World</div>);
}; export default TransactionList;
```

Comment: React state updates are asynchronous, so you will not able to get the `searchFilter` data immediately after setting the state `setSearchFilter({ ... })` . Try moving the console `console.log(searchFilter.transactionId)` outside of the function.

Comment: try useLayoutEffect.